# How to output the symbol of sufficient and unnecessary condition in LaTex?

Tags: symbols, arrows

[image]

How to output the symbol of  sufficient and unnecessary condition in LaTex? I have browsed a number of websites, but none is satisfactory. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  To the best of my knowledge, this is not available as a distinct symbol/character, so it will probably have to be constructed.

Comment: Thanks for your knowledge!

Comment: I'd name it “sufficient but not necessary”. Personally I would restrain from using it, for it is very informal and doesn't belong to “logic”. Perhaps you want to use it in some summarizing diagram or table, do you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a construction of the symbol with `old-arrows`' arrows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[old]{old-arrows}
\newlength{\longwidth}
\newlength{\longheight}
\settowidth{\longwidth}{$\varlongrightarrow$}
\settoheight{\longheight}{$\varlongrightarrow$}
\newcommand{\sufficient}{%
    \mathrel{%
        \raisebox{ .65\longheight}{$\varlongrightarrow$}\hspace*{-\longwidth}%
        \raisebox{-.25\longheight}{$\varlongleftarrow$}\hspace*{-\longwidth}%
        \makebox[\longwidth]{\raisebox{-.15\longheight}{$\smallsetminus$}}%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\(A \sufficient B\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm so moved by your patient work, thank you so much!

Comment: `\longheight` is defined exactly as `\longwidth`, this looks like a typo.

Comment: Looks very nice.  Does it hold up when used, say, in a lower limit?

Comment: @frougon It was indeed a typo, thanks for pointing it out! I corrected the code, it makes more sense now.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Unfortunately it will not scale with the font size. I figured it was not too bad since it's meant to indicate implications, so it should not have to be used often in subscripts or superscripts.

Answer (score 1):

With some low level programming:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\suffnotnec}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \vcenter{%
      \offinterlineskip
      \ialign{##\cr
        $\longrightarrow$\cr
        \vphantom{$\longleftarrow$}%
        \ooalign{%
          $\longleftarrow$\cr
          \hidewidth\raisebox{\depth}{$\scriptscriptstyle\backslash$}\hidewidth\cr
        }\cr
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$A\suffnotnec B$

\end{document}
```

A `\mathrel` is built. In it a vertical box that's centered at the formula axis (`\vcenter`) containing a simple alignment: on top a `\longrightarrow`, at the bottom a `\longleftarrow` with a small `\backslash` superimposed to it with `\ooalign`. The `\backslash` is in `\scriptscriptstyle` and raised by its depth. The `\vphantom` is needed for technical reasons (in order to fix height and depth of the `\ooalign` construction).

[image]